# how to instal ubuntu 13.10 [pre downloaded] over windows 7 using wubi?

Tags: wubi, system-installation

I have pre downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 ISO . I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 pre downloaded ISO using Wubi without downloading it again during the installation of Wubi . Is there any possibilites like that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you save the downloaded ISO in the same directory you're executing wubi from, lets say, your desktop, wubi should detect it and use it as a source for the installation.